# asp.net mvc application restarting every second without reason

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5, windows-server-2012

I have an issue with an asp.net mvc 4 web application that when it comes under load, it starts restarting every second. It is running on Windows Server 2012 and IIS 7.5. This also results in the CPU hitting 100% until its app pool gets recycled. I found that the app was getting recycled by adding logging to the Application_End method in global.asax with logging the HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason to a text file. This tells me that the application is being restarted with the following details: Reason: ConfigurationChange

However I am not aware of what configuration change is occuring or what is causing such. Researching on the internal is not helping and need to get insight in to such. I noticed though the Process ID is not changing.

As an aside, I noticed in the event viewer critical errors being logged at the same time under Microsoft > Windows > Application Server-Applications > Operational. Exceptions being

```
    Unhandled exception.  Exception details: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitMultiple(WaitHandle[] waitHandles, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext, Boolean WaitAll)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(WaitHandle[] waitHandles, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadTimer.TimerManager.OnWaitCallback(Object state)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
```

Any tips or information as to where the issue here is, what is causing the restarts? Any tools or tips to assist?

Any feedback would be great.

Comment: Does anything within this application or any other application write to the file system within this application's directory?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I checked this and no its not the case. However to make 100% sure, is there any tool I could use to monitory changes?

Comment: Maybe have a read through: http://forums.asp.net/t/970884.aspx?Random+Unexpected+AppDomain+Restarts

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Did you manage to find the cause of it?

Answer (score 0):

Check your application app pool recycle configuration. There is a virtual memory threshold that can causes the app pool to be recycled.

Comment: Yes I checked this and it is not set to recycle.

Answer (score 0):

Any exception thrown out of process will restart the application pool. Any asynchronous tasks are considered out of process so that's why it's restarting your app pool.

Comment: Interesting - how could I track this down? I do have some async tasks.

Comment: Just debug your application and the Visual Studio IDE will tell you which thread(s) are throwing the exception. You'll notice the thread number on the top toolbar. If the thread is different than your starting thread, then you know it's a separate thread is throwing the exception :)